# how to quickly check if an object is in a list in python

Tags: python-2.7, python

I have a list of objects, each of the same kind.

Each object has its own list of objects (usually just 5-10 items)

What I used to do was:

```
for o in main_object_list:
    obj_list = o.get_this_object_list()
    for i in obj_list:
        if i in main_object_list:
            //do something with i
```

While this approach works, when main_object_list has, say, 100.000 elements,
it goes horribly slow.

My workaround has been this:

```
for o in main_object_list:
    o.flag = True 

for o in main_object_list:
    obj_list = o.get_this_object_list()
    for i in obj_list:
        if i.flag:
            //do something with i
```

It goes several orders of magnitude faster (from 22 minutes to as little as 17 secs)
but I suspect there may be a different, and better, approach. Moreover, this example works just becaue each object has a flag property, and by the way it is not so
elegant to use a flag that may well have been setted/unsetted in other functions
(if this function is called in the body of a parent function which uses the same
flag mechanisms, this would mess everything up, setting every objects flag)

Is there a more correct pythonesque way to quickly check if an object is in
main_object_list?

Comment: Better approach is to use a set if all the objects are unique and hashable

Comment: You need to call each object in main_object_list many times and with correct order, aren't you? 
You really need do something for quite each pair of main_object_list, say near 10.000.000.000 times? How that can be faster?

Comment: [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) in Python 2.6 and up, [`sets.Set`](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) down to Python 2.3.

Comment: every object is hashable and unique, the list is actually a set under this point of view. I tried using set (and dict). It GOES faster, but I gain just 10-15% in speed. I do not need to process each list in a prticular order btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your own flag, you could do:

```
for o in main_object_list:
    o.my_special_flag = True 

for o in main_object_list:
    obj_list = o.get_this_object_list()
    for i in obj_list:
        if hasattr(i, 'my_special_flag'):
```

Otherwise `set.intersection` is as fast as it gets:

```
main_object_set = set(main_object_list)

for o in main_object_list:
    obj_list = o.get_this_object_list()
    objs_in_main_list = main_object_set.intersection(obj_list)
    for i in objs_in_main_list:
        //do something with i
```

Or:

```
main_object_set = set(main_object_list)

objs_in_main_list = set().update(
                           *(o.get_this_object_list() for o in main_object_list))
objs_in_main_list.intersection_update(main_object_set)
```

Comment: I tried set, but didnt try set.intersection (or set & set), just didnt think it could be faster than 'in'

Comment: @user815129 It does lots of `in`s at once, in C, without returning to the Python level. It should be faster.

Comment: @user815129 The other possibility is to use your own flag; see my edit.